# Распиновка 8 жильной витой пары

Tags: сеть

Есть такая схема сети:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно соединить ПК с роутером или коммутатором, использовать такую распиновку:

TIA/EIA-568B

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а если нужно соединить роутеры и коммутаторы между собой, использовать следующую распиновку:

crossover cable (1000 Мбит/с)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И там же пишется, что современные сетевые карты сами могут определять как распинован кабель, и можно всегда использовать вариант TIA/EIA-568B.

Как правильнее сделать?

Роутер#1, Роутер#2 и коммутатор между собой соединить crossover cable (1000 Мбит/с), или можно все соединить TIA/EIA-568B?

Пострадает от решения скорость локальной сети?

Comment: Насколько я помню, кроссовер кабель нужен был только для соединения двух сетевых карт напрямую без роутера (нужен был раньше, когда сетевые карты не умели определять, как распинован кабель). Для соединения сетевой карты с роутером кроссовер не нужен (ни раньше, ни сейчас)

Comment: @insolor это я не совсем правильно написал (ну или совсем неправильно понял....)
кроссовер использовать когда нужно соединить пк с пк или роутер с коммутатор (роутер с роуте или коммутатор с коммутатор) или я совсем неправильно понял?

Comment: Да где ж сейчас найдёшь такую древность, которая не знает MDI/MDIX? да ещё чтобы с обеих сторон кабеля... делай прямой кабель по схеме В и не засоряй себе мозг.

Comment: @Руслан кроссовер раньше использовался при соединении ПК с ПК (сетевая карта к сетевой карте). В остальных случаях использовался "прямой" кабель. Сейчас практически всегда можно использовать "прямой" кабель.

Comment: @insolor Раньше и свитчи/хабы не имели автоопределения и на них даже на случай прямых кабелей были специальные перекресные порты или кнопка переключения в кросс режим. Так что такие кабели вполне могли пригодиться по соединении не только карта-карта. Но да, сейчас все оборудование само все понимает настолько, что все уже забыли как оно было :)

Comment: @Руслан Кросс кабели с гигабитом вообще не совместимы. Если нужна связь на гигабите то кабель должен быть только прямым, с одинаковой разводкой на обоих концах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перекрёстный порядок обжимки утратил свой смысл 10-15 лет назад. Только университетские методички ещё помнят про всякие кросс-распиновки.

В мире современных сетевых адаптеров перекрёстный порядок не применяется.
Главное правило обжимки: последовательности цветов жил на обоих концах должны соответствовать друг другу.

Если же вам требуется гигабитная скорость, соблюдайте не только соответствие цветов, а ещё именно тот порядок их следования, который указан в TIA/EIA-568B.